# What's this function called: $a^2 + b^2 + 2(ab)$?

Tags: arithmetic

This is a formula for calculating the 2th power of a number, for example if you want to calculate the 2th power of 5:

$\begin{align*}
a&= 2\\
b&= 3
\end{align*}$

$ 5^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2(ab)$

Sorry if that's not the right notation, but you'll get the point. Question is, what's the formula/method called?

Comment: That's a binomial expansion.

Comment: [Binomial expansions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) are $$(a+b)^1=a^1+b^1 $$ $$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$$ $$(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$$ $$(a+b)^4=a^4+4a^3b+6a^2b^2+4ab^3+b^4$$ and so on.

Comment: @anon, could you make an answer out of that so that I can confirm it as the best one;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As J. M. and lhf said, this is an example of a [Binomial expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem). Other examples include $$(a+b)^1=a^1+b^1$$ $$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$$ $$(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$$ $$(a+b)^4=a^4+4a^3b+6a^2b^2+4ab^3+b^4$$ and so on. The coefficient of the factor $a^m b^{n-m}$ in the expansion of $(a+b)^n$ is the number of ways of picking $m$ instances of $a$ out of $n$ possible instances of $a$ or $b$, which is the binomial coefficient $${n\choose m}=\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}.$$

Answer (score 2):

It's just the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) for the second power. Or you can just expand $(a+b)^2= (a+b)\cdot(a+b)= a\cdot a + b \cdot a + a\cdot b + b \cdot b = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$.